# Two.JS rendering from different scopes

Tags: javascript, electron, two.js

I'm building a desktop application using [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) and [Two.js](https://two.js.org/). The application is basically a 2D level editor. There are `Tile` objects which represent `32x32` tiles in game. There's an array of Tile objects and I have tried to draw them using `Two.JS` but as it turns out `two`is not able to find renderable stuff which are not in the same scope as `two.update()`

I have tried creating a group using `two.makeGroup()` and then while looping Tile objects, i've tried adding them to the group using `two.add(newRect)`. No luck.

Doing it this way doesn't work at all. (out of scope?)

```
for (let i = 0; i < tiles.length-1; i++) {
    let rect = two.makeRectangle(tiles[i].getX(), tiles[i].getY(), size, size);
    rect.fill = 'rgb('+tiles[i].color[0]+', '+tiles[i].color[1]+', '+tiles[i].color[2]+')';
    rect.noStroke();

}

two.update();
```

but this way works quite fine for some reason

```
let rect = two.makeRectangle(tiles[i].getX(), tiles[i].getY(), size, size);
rect.fill = 'rgb('+tiles[i].color[0]+', '+tiles[i].color[1]+', '+tiles[i].color[2]+')';
rect.noStroke();

two.update();
```

**My question is: How do I render multiple objects from different scopes?**

(where it doesn't draw) this function is where im trying to draw from : https://github.com/idontreallywolf/gyarb_mapper/blob/750eddc6cbb179d359c47b4fc6711c9e79a0472d/renderer.js#L73

EDIT : (where it is able to draw)
I tried adding a random function, it worked with this one. For some reason the previous scope is not (detected?)

```
function troll(){
    let rect = two.makeRectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
    rect.fill = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    rect.stroke = "#f00";
}

troll();
two.update();
```

## **UPDATE:**

Two.js wasn't able to draw them because the variables that I've used as parameters were inaccessible in that scope, so after doing some debugging I've solved the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum working example so it could be executed? For example for this particular case you could try to create a snippet right here on StackOverflow. If I understand right using `Electron` is not related to the issue described.

Comment: I believe you can get the basic working version from my git repository : https://github.com/idontreallywolf/gyarb_mapper

Comment: I believe you've not reproduced the issue in that repository, have you?

Comment: I haven't, but if you create a funciton and then try to draw something inside it, you will be able to reproduce the issue

Comment: @falinsky EDIT: i was wrong, haven't found the issue. But if you check out my last commit, you can see the part where it doesn't want to draw https://github.com/idontreallywolf/gyarb_mapper/commit/80c52fe2834f6b07d6d8e3ad5e4209cbb1b98fcc